# How to restructure a matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a matrix like below:

```
mat = {{{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}}, {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}}}
```

I want to change it to

```
{{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}}
```

I have tried `Flatten` function, but was unable to achieve my goal.

Comment: `Flatten[#, 1] & /@ mat` which is just `Map[Flatten[#, 1] &, mat]`. See also [Pure Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html).

Comment: `Flatten /@ mat`

Comment: `Join @@@ mat`..

Comment: `ArrayReshape[mat,{2,4}]`

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways (shown by people in the comments). Personally, I find this one to be the cleanest:

```
mat[[All, All, 1]]
```

Take `All` rows, `All` columns, and then the `1`st element from the list within.

Answer (score 2):

Partition is your friend here, when things get confusing. First `Flatten` it all the way out.

```
res=Flatten[mat]
```

> {a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d}

Now `Partition` into blocks of 4 elements

```
Partition[res,4]
```

> {{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}}

---

**Edit**

As a performance check, I ran the following tests on the methods in the initial comments, and @Szabolcs's answer. Listed in rank ordering of timing performance. `ArrayReshape` for the win, but `Flatten-Partition` in 2nd. EDIT: Surprisingly, it was a little faster to break up the `Flatten-Partition` into two steps rather than embed them.

```
mat = RandomInteger[100, {10,000,000, 4, 1}];

AbsoluteTiming[res1 = ArrayReshape[mat, {Length[mat], 4}];]
{0.23, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[res = Flatten@mat; Partition[res, 4];]
{.37, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[Partition[Flatten@mat, 4];]
{0.41, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[res4 = Flatten[mat, {{1}, {2, 3}}];]
{0.523814, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[mat[[All, All, 1]];]
{0.63, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[Flatten /@ mat;]
{1.69, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[Map[Flatten[#, 1] &, mat];]
{1.74, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[Flatten[#, 1] & /@ mat;]
{1.77, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[Join @@@ mat;]
{19.4, Null}
```

Comment: Uhh, why the negative votes?

Comment: Negative votes probably because your solution is not a recommended way. It goes too far with `Flatten` and then backtracks with `Partition`, for which (i) you need the original sublist length 4, and (ii) you assume that all sublists are of equal length. See the above comments for direct solutions without backtracking.

Comment: OK, but I think you've read more into his question than he put in there. While the methods in the comments above all work, many of them require digging into the docs to understand *why* exactly they work (awesome learning exercise for the novice). Clever but not intuitive. The `Flatten-Partition` approach is a no-brainer that allows you to implement and move on, and when you are dealing with 2 x 4 matrices...

Comment: For completeness, please test `Flatten[mat, {{1}, {2, 3}}]` as well.

Comment: Done, you get the Bronze medal. :)

Comment: You have a point!